# ROS melodic rviz problem

Tags: ros-melodic, rviz, plugin, visualization

Hi I'm using ROS melodic and I was trying my own global_planner using plugin method.
before changing the base_global_planner to my "own global planner" it was using navfn.

After changing the planner and when I started navigation, in rviz the path doesn't appear but moves.So I thought my planner worked but when I tried rostopic echo /move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan nothing appears and still the move_base/Navfn topic is still in the list.So now I'm confused about two things.

1.Does it mean my planner worked but the topic name is wrong?

2.Plugin didn't changed and navfn is used?

If somebody knows anything plz leave a comment any suggestions will be welcomed to me!
Thank you for reading